# Magento 2.1 add dynamic row in custom page

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created dynamic rows in system config as below.

```
<group id="jet_attributes" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="16" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Attributes</label>
    <field id="customer_attributes" translate="label" sortOrder="16" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
        <label>Magento - Jet Attribute IDs</label>
        <frontend_model>Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Attribute</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>Company\Module\Model\System\Config\Backend\Attribute</backend_model>
    </field>
</group>
```

/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/Attribute.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

class Attribute extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{

    protected $_columns = [];
    protected $_customerGroupRenderer;

    protected $_addAfter = true;
    protected $_addButtonLabel;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    /*public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }*/

    /**
     * Initialise form fields
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }

    protected function getCustomerGroupRenderer() {
        if (!$this->_customerGroupRenderer) {
            $this->_customerGroupRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    '\Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\MageAttributes', '', ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->_customerGroupRenderer;
    }


    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
                'magento', 
                [
                'label' => __('Magento Attribute Id'),
                'renderer' => $this->getCustomerGroupRenderer()
                ]
            );
        $this->addColumn('jet', ['label' => __('Jet Attribute Id')]);

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }


    protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
        $customerGroup = $row->getCustomerGroup();
        $options = [];
        if ($customerGroup) {
            $options['option_' . $this->getCustomerGroupRenderer()->calcOptionHash($customerGroup)] = 'selected="selected"';
        }
        $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
    }

    public function renderCellTemplate($columnName)
    {
        if ($columnName == "jet") {
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['class'] = 'input-text required-entry validate-number';
            $this->_columns[$columnName]['style'] = 'width:50px';
        }
        return parent::renderCellTemplate($columnName);
    }


}
```

/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/MageAttributes.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;
class MageAttributes extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select {
   /**
     * methodList
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $groupfactory;
   /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Braintree\Model\System\Config\Source\Country $countrySource
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory $groupfactory, 
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->groupfactory = $groupfactory;
    }  
    /**
     * Returns countries array
     *
     * @return array
     */ 
     /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function _toHtml() {
        if (!$this->getOptions()) {
            $customerGroupCollection = $this->groupfactory->create()->getCollection();
            foreach ($customerGroupCollection as $customerGroup) {
                     $this->addOption($customerGroup->getCustomerGroupId(), $customerGroup->getCustomerGroupCode());
            }
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
    /**
     * Sets name for input element
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setInputName($value) {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }
}
```

I am able to get proper result in system configuration.

But I want to add same screen in my custom page. So how can I achieve this?